# Disabling the edit button in grid view when with the help of date field condition using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, oracle, oracle10g

I am new to the asp.net, and sorry for grammar mistakes.

I have 3 fields in my table, `name`, `age` and `created_date`. I used the grid view to display all the fields on a web form. Later, I added a `command` column and then converted it to a template field.

I need to disable the edit button based on `created_date`; i.e `if created_date + 5 > sysdate`
then I need to disable the edit button.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an asp.net button something like this may do the trick

```
<asp:Button ID="Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" ... 
    Enabled='<%# ((DateTime)Eval("created_date")).AddDays(5) > DateTime.Now ? false : true %>'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code on your code behine to implement a RowDataBound event for the gridview:

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs  e)
{
    // check if this row is on the edit state
    if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {
        // get date_created from bind
        DateTime date_created = Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "date_created"));

        // check if from this date more 5 days if greather than now
        if(date_created.AddDays(5) > DateTime.Now)
        {
            // disable button
            ((Button) e.Row.FindControl("btnEdit")).Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And on the asp.net server tag you can reference this event on the gridview tag:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound">
...
</asp:GridView>
```